# mod_rewrite to ISAPI Rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, isapi-rewrite

my .htaccess code as below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.intelligent-t.com/404
```

How to create httpd.ini  file with the same above roles  ???

Answer (score 0):

There is no alternative for ErrorDocument directive and RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f in ISAPI_Rewrite 2, but the closest config will look like this:

```
[ISAPI_Rewrite]

RewriteRule /(?!(?:list|of|physical|files|and|folders))([^\.]+)$ /$1.php [I,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not working. First role to remove file extension ( .php ), second role to redirect the visitor to 404.php file if URL not found.